# Aligning five columns in a bootstrap template with first aligned left, last aligned right, and the rest evenly spaced

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a change to my template which was originally built around bootstrap 3.3.
I have one div set as

```
col-md-offset-2 col-md-8
```

Inside that are two rows. The second row will contain five social media icons, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get the first icon to be aligned with the left of the row above, the last to be aligned with the right, and the remaining icons to spread out so there is an equal distance between each.

The best I've managed so far does give me an equal distance between all icons, but they are not positioned to match the width of the row above.

I set up a fiddle to help show the problem, and what my current code is. You'll need a viewport of 992px and above. https://jsfiddle.net/ehgp0yw5/

What is the correct way to approach situations such as this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
.social {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```